# Rails nested form only adding one Passenger Object to a Booking

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The form below renders the correct HTML so a user can enter multiple passenger information into a form, yet when i debug to see what the form is submitting it only has 1 passenger's details when there could be up to 4 passengers per booking.

```
<%= form_for @booking do |f| %>
  <% params[:passengers].to_i.times do %>
    <%= f.fields_for @passenger do |addy_form|%>
      <%= addy_form.text_field :name, placeholder: "name" %>
      <%= addy_form.text_field :email, placeholder: "email"%>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <%= hidden_field_tag(:flight_id, params[:flight_id]) %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag(:scheduled_for, params[:scheduled_for]) %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag(:from_airport, params[:from_airport]) %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag(:to_airport, params[:to_airport]) %>

   <%= f.submit 'Confirm Booking' %>
<% end %>
```

Booking Controller

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @booking = Booking.new
    @passenger = Passenger.new
  end
end
```

EDIT: added params below that the form is submitting. In the form I added 2 passenger's details, 1) John - john@mail.com 2) sarah - sarah@mail.com

```
{"authenticity_token"=>"egDf-wifNMx4PzXQdFNpv_3NXnRyWp007D8klnMu-D3Hc47vKUVmJc1ehs-8RcV8SPapPG-bVPSTqLeu9M-A-w", "booking"=>{"passenger"=>{"name"=>"sarah", "email"=>"sarah@mail.com"}}, "flight_id"=>"9", "scheduled_for"=>"2021-02-10 23:15:00 UTC", "from_airport"=>"1", "to_airport"=>"2", "commit"=>"Confirm Booking", "controller"=>"bookings", "action"=>"create"}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are overriding the value of `@Passenger` multiple times with the new value entered.

You should initialize passengers in the controller.

```rb
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @booking = Booking.new
    params[:passengers].to_i.times do 
      @booking.passengers.build
    end
  end
end
```

and update the view to be like the [main docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#understanding-parameter-naming-conventions-the-fields-for-helper) using `@booking.passengers`

Comment: Thanks but the form is still only passing one passenger into the params?

Answer (score 0):

With guidance from Magzy's answer and also I missed out adding this to my booking model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :passengers
```